# AutoMapper ITypeConverter issue

Tags: c#, type-conversion, automapper, data-conversion

I have the following models:

```
public class DeviceSuspensionRequest : BaseEntity
{
    //.....
    public DeviceSuspensionRequestState State { get; set; }
    //.....
}

public class RequestDto : BaseEntity
{
    //.....
    public RequestStatusDto State { get; set; }
    //.....
}
```

and the following AutoMapper profile class:

```
public class AutoMapperEFRequest : AutoMapper.Profile
{
    public AutoMapperEFRequest()
    {
        CreateMap<DeviceSuspensionRequestState, RequestStatusDto>().ConvertUsing<SuspensionStatusConverter>();

        CreateMap<DeviceSuspensionRequest, RequestDto>()
            //.....
            ;

    }

    public class SuspensionStatusConverter : ITypeConverter<DeviceSuspensionRequestState, RequestStatusDto>
    {

        public RequestStatusDto Convert(DeviceSuspensionRequestState source, RequestStatusDto destination, ResolutionContext context)
        {
            switch (source)
            {
                case DeviceSuspensionRequestState.RequestSuspensionState:
                    return RequestStatusDto.RequestActive;
                    break;
                case DeviceSuspensionRequestState.SuspendedState:
                    return RequestStatusDto.Accepted;
                    break;
                case DeviceSuspensionRequestState.RequestReactivationState:
                    return RequestStatusDto.ReactivationRequest;
                    break;
                case DeviceSuspensionRequestState.ReactivatedState:
                    return RequestStatusDto.Reactivated;
                    break;
                case DeviceSuspensionRequestState.CancelBySuperadminState:
                    return RequestStatusDto.Cancelled;
                    break;
                case DeviceSuspensionRequestState.CancelByCompanyadminState:
                    return RequestStatusDto.Cancelled;
                    break;
                default:
                    return RequestStatusDto.Unknown;
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Map:

```
    _mapperConfig = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
    {
        cfg.AddProfile<AutoMapperEFRequest>();
    });

    _mapperConfig.AssertConfigurationIsValid();
```

it's passed

but when I try to do the following:

```
    var query =
        (from suspensionRequest in _context.DeviceSuspensionRequests select suspensionRequest).ProjectTo<RequestDto>(_mapperConfig)
        .OrderBy(p => p.RequestDateTime)
        ;
```

it throws the following ArgumentException exception:

> 'Argument types do not match'

what is incorrect?

Comment: Are you suggesting that the exception is caused by the type converter? If so, why?

Comment: A repro would help. Make a [gist](https://gist.github.com/lbargaoanu/9c7233441c3a3413cc2b9b9ebb5964a9) that we can execute and see fail.

Comment: @devNull because it works fine if I add to ignore `State` field (or rename it)

Comment: @LucianBargaoanu I got the following: `DeviceSuspensionRequest -> RequestDto (Destination member list)\r\nTms.Core.Domain.Devices.DeviceSuspensionRequest -> Tms.Core.Dto.DeviceManagement.RequestDto (Destination member list)\r\n\r\n`

Comment: What's that got to do with anything? Can you make a repro?

Comment: @LucianBargaoanu Ok, I removed all unmapped fields, right now `config.AssertConfigurationIsValid();` is passed, but I get the same error: `"Argument types do not match"`

Comment: @LucianBargaoanu I added details to my question

Comment: https://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Queryable-Extensions.html#supported-mapping-options

Comment: @LucianBargaoanu but I use type converter, not value converter

Comment: @LucianBargaoanu ok, how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

In AM 10, `ProjectTo` will map your enums by default using the underlying numeric value, so if those values match, the mapping will work without a type converter. Otherwise, you need the `Expression` based `ConvertUsing` overload. Any other overload works only with `Map`, as [the docs](https://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Queryable-Extensions.html#supported-mapping-options) say.

Comment: "Otherwise, you need the Expression based ConvertUsing overload" - how to do it? Do you have an example of it?

Comment: There are many examples here, in the AM repo and elsewhere online. Give it a shot :)

Comment: sorry, probably, I'm stupid, but I really don't understand what means under "you need the Expression based ConvertUsing overload". I can't google anything... As I understand, problem is because that type converter can't be processed to Linq-to-entities, right?

Comment: Yes. But you _have to understand_ what expressions are. Forget about the answer to some question. You need to do some research so you can understand what the docs assume you already know.